# Google Firestore "Collections failed to load"

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Google Firestore console is not showing existing collections and not allowing me to create new collection. Its showing an error "Collections failed to load" on the console. I tried logging-out and logging-in but nothing changed. I am the owner of the project and I was able to use Firestore till last week.

Answer (score 0):

It's typically been a temporary issue for my team.

- Try a different browser.
- Try refreshing the cache on the browser.
- Try accessing it via the Firebase console (and not the GCP console).
- Try changing to a different profile, then back again (if you have multiple Google accounts), or going to a different project, then back to that one.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).